# facing issue in connecting to cluster mode disabled redis cluster in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, redis

`I tried this following code,

```
func (rs *RedisClient) Initialise() *RedisClient {
   if rs.enable {
      if rs.instanceDefiner {
         rs.client = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
            Addr:     rs.RedisHosts,
            Password: "", // no password set
            DB:       0,  // use default DB
         })
      } else {
         rs.clusterClient = redis.NewClusterClient(&redis.ClusterOptions{
            Addrs: strings.Split(rs.RedisHosts, ","),
         })
         ctx := context.TODO()
         pong, err := rs.clusterClient.Ping(ctx).Result()
         if err != nil {
            logger.Error("Redis connectivity unsuccessful", "err", err)
         } else {
            logger.Info("redis connectivity successful", "ping", pong)
         }
      }
   }
   return rs
}
```

When I am passing host name as master.usw02-dev-timeseries-v11-migration.jlpe80.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379.

It says cluster mode is disabled is not supported..

I am expecting that I should be able to connect to redis cache.`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "NewUniversalClient"?

Try this if you are using 'redis/v8';

```
func (rs *RedisClient) Initialise() *RedisClient {
    if rs.enable {
        rs.client = redis.NewUniversalClient(&redis.UniversalOptions{
            Addrs:    strings.Split(rs.RedisHosts, ","),
            Password: "", // no password set
            DB:       0,  // use default DB
        })

        ctx := context.TODO()
        pong, err := rs.client.Ping(ctx).Result()
        if err != nil {
            logger.Error("connectivity unsuccessful", "err", err)
        } else {
            logger.Info("connectivity successful", "ping", pong)
        }
    }
    return rs
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting this below error ::  read tcp 10.72.x.x:34570->10.x.x.x:6379: i/o timeout.

Comment: I also tried giving all the endpoint of cluster, but it gives me below error :: dial tcp: lookup  usw02-dev-timeseries-v11-migration-002.usw02-dev-timeseries-v11-migration.jlpe80.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com: no such host

Comment: The first error indicates a timeout issue when trying to connect to the Redis server. This could be due to network latency, incorrect server configuration, or wrong connection settings.

Check if the Redis server is running and accepting connections by running the redis-cli command-line tool or using telnet/nc:

'redis-cli -h hostname -p port ping' or 'telnet'

Ensure that the Redis server's hostname can be resolved by your machine. You can test this by using the 'nslookup' or 'dig'

Comment: I installed redis cli on the EC2 instance. When I am trying to connect to cluster mode  enabled cluster, redis-cli is working. But for cluster mode disabled its not working.Encryption is there in cluster mode disabled cluster.